# How to handle conflicting function and variable names?

Tags: c++

I'm writing a simple socket C++ class and it looks like this:

```
class Socket {

public:
    // ...
    void connect();

private:
    // ...
    int socket;

};
```

There are two issues with my class:

1. `void Socket::connect()`
   I'm using the native Linux socket interface, which means there is already a function called `int connect(...)` that I want to use inside the `Socket::connect()` function.
2. `int socket`
   Same problem. The class variable name has a conflicting name with the `int socket(...)` function.

Question: Am I forced to change the name of the `int socket` and `void connect()` to something else, or is there a workaround?

Comment: Write a simple test case without the sockets library. Just define a global function named `connect` and a global variable named `socket` and experiment. Global names that are the same as member names can be accessed with a `::` qualifier.

Comment: Though your problem *can* be solved, I would still suggest to change your variable and function name ... it can help you (and whoever comes after you to maintain this code) to stay our of trouble.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The global names can be used by using the global scoping operator, `::`.

Inside the class, you can use `::connect` and `::socket` to use the global functions. To call the global functions, use `::connect(...)` and `::socket(...)`.